# Finding maximum using apply and embed in R in Quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod, quantstrat

hi i was looking at this website

http://www.r-bloggers.com/backtesting-a-simple-stock-trading-strategy/

but I couldn't understand this code below:

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols('^GSPC',from='1900-01-01')

daysSinceHigh <- function(x, n){
       apply(embed(x, n), 1, which.max)-1
    }

myStrat <- function(x, nHold=100, nHigh=200) {
    position <- ifelse(daysSinceHigh(x, nHigh)<=nHold,1,0)
    c(rep(0,nHigh-1),position)
}
```

my question is that if you embed(x,1) then it transforms time-series object(GSPC) into matrix. right?

but if you apply which.max function into this matrix wouldn't it find the index(location) of the maximum value(for example, maximum volume in this case)?

not maximum price since you are searching for every element in the matrix.

and Why do you subtract 1 to it?

He explained it in the post but i couldn't understand how it worked...

Comment: You're only quoting part of the blog post. `myStrat(...)` is called with `Cl(GSPC)`, which has one column: the closing price for each day. So `embed(x,n=200)` produces a matrix with 200 columns and `nrow(sp500)-199` rows. Each row of this matrix contains the prices in a rolling 200 day window, starting at day 1. `apply(embed(x,200),1,which.max)` applies `which.max(...)` row-wise and for each row returns the column number of the maximum price in that window. Try the example in the docs for `embed(...)` to see how it works.

Comment: oh I see.... they make each row one cycle. I couldn't understand the concept. Thank you so much!